# fixed div overlaps/hide the next div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to have 2 footer.The first footer should be fixed as page scrolls, as scroll reaches page end, footer1 should rest/placed before the footer2.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
    body{
        margin: 0;
    }
    #header{
        height: 100px;
        background: orange;
    }
    #body{
        height: 10000px;
        background: white;
    }
    #footer1{
        height: 100px;
        background: darkblue;
    }
    .footer-sticky{
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: pink;
    }
    #footer2{
        height: 100px;
        background: green;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="body"></div>

    <div id="footer1" style="position:fixed;bottom: 0;right: 0;left: 0;background: black;height:50px;color:white;">footer1</div>
    <div id="footer2" style="">footer2</div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Program includes 2 footer.The first footer should be fixed as page scrolls, as scroll reaches page end, footer1 should rest/placed before the footer2.
Here's jsfiddle link 
http://jsfiddle.net/dLe5cv4j/

Comment: maybe you need a bit of javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/5v18x1yk/

Answer (score 3):

add `position: relative;` to the body and insert this javascript at the end (or inside the page load event)

```
var f1 = document.getElementById("footer1");
var f2 = document.getElementById("footer2");
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
    if (document.body.scrollTop + window.innerHeight >
        document.body.scrollHeight - f2.clientHeight ) {
        f1.style.position = "absolute";
        f1.style.bottom = f2.clientHeight+"px";
    }
    else{
        f1.style.position = "fixed";
        f1.style.bottom = "0px";
    }
});
```

Result: [http://jsfiddle.net/Lkuy0ext/](http://jsfiddle.net/Lkuy0ext/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Add in your styles may work you

```
#footer1
{
z-index: 1;
}

#footer2 
{
position: relative;
z-index: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#footer1{
   margin-bottom:100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: darkblue;
}
```

edit and try.